# Use the two properties of $S$ to show that $S =\mathbb N$

Tags: induction, solution-verification, natural-numbers

Assume $S \subseteq \mathbb N$ such that:

- $\forall k \in \mathbb N :2^k \in S$
- $\forall k \ge 1: k \in S \implies k-1 \in S$

Show that $S =\mathbb N$.

---

It's left to show that $\mathbb N \subseteq S$.

Let $P(n)$ be the proposition such that $\left\{ 2^k-n, ...,2^k\right\} \subseteq S$.

The base case is true since $P(0)$ means $\left\{ 2^k\right\} \subseteq S$ which is true by the hypothesis.

Assume $P(n)$ does hold and consider $P(n+1)$,from the assumption $\left\{ 2^k-n, ...,2^k\right\} \subseteq S$ which implies $2^k-n \in S$ From the second property of $S$ it's clear that $2^k-(n+1)= 2^k-n-1 \in S$ and so $\left\{ 2^k-(n+1), ...,2^k\right\} \subseteq S$.
Since this is true for all natural $n$ so $S =\mathbb N$.

---

**Edit**:

Another way I tried:
Let $P(n)$ be the proposition such that $\left\{ 0, ...,2^n\right\} \subseteq S$.

The base case is true since $2^0 \in S$ which is true by the first property of $S$ and from the other property, we see that $0 \in S$.

Assume $P(n)$ does hold and consider $P(n+1)$,from the assumption $\left\{ 0, ...,2^n\right\} \subseteq S$.The set $\left\{0,...,2^{n+1}\right\}$ can be written as $\left\{0,...,2^{n}\right\} \cup \left\{2^{n}+1,...,2^{n+1}\right\}$,again from the first property of $S$, $2^{n+1} \in S$,the second property implies $2^{n+1}-1 \in S$,continuing this way we see that $\left\{2^{n}+1,...,2^{n+1}\right\} \subseteq S$,and so $$\left\{0,...,2^{n+1}\right\}=\left\{0,...,2^{n}\right\} \cup \left\{2^{n}+1,...,2^{n+1}\right\}\subseteq S$$

---

It would be highly appreciated if someone checks the validity of the proofs.

Comment: For me your proof is correct.

Comment: I don't understand how $P(n)$ is relevant here, can you explain how your work implies that $S= \mathbb{N}$? I don't believe you have proven that if you take a natural number, that number must be in $S$.

Comment: As a side note, the standard proof of the AM-GM inequality (at least the one I know) follows this induction pattern.

Comment: In second proof: $P(n)$ is $\left\{ 0, ...,2^n\right\} \subseteq S$ in first line, but then in 4-th line you have "from the assumption $\left\{ 1, ...,2^n\right\} \subseteq S$" - first member is $0$ or $1$?

Comment: Ok, now for me second one is also fine.

Comment: About which reason you are speaking?

Comment: zkutch can you explain to me why you think proof $1$ is correct?

Comment: 45464 I think you are missing the whole idea behind the proof. For example, even if your logic worked for your second proof, you still would need the fact that every natural number can be written between $0$ and some power of two, which you have not proved! (And is really the crux of the issue, of which I have addressed below). I don't know why you ask for help when you ignore the person explaining how you're wrong

Comment: @Derek Luna. Do you see mistake somewhere in proof 1?

Comment: I don't know what you've been looking at. It does not explicitly prove the statement, it is just a rehashing of the hypothesis.

Comment: You will find that to explicitly prove that that set is not bounded, you will need a similar argument to mine. Since you have to actually find a power of $2$ greater than the supposed upper bound $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the following:
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $n$ is a power of two we are done. Otherwise $n=2^ka$ with $(a,2)=1$ for some $k$. Since $2^a > a$ for all $a$ by a simple induction, $2^ka<2^{k+a} \in S$. and by property $(2)$, $n \in S$.

Comment: I don't understand your proof that well to be honest. ($P(n)$ is true for all $n$ straight from the definition of $S$, and I don't see how this further implies that $S =  \mathbb{N}$ anyways). I thought this was more elegant so I thought I'd share.

Comment: OP if I were you I'd voted Derek's answer up and said nothing but "thank you" because I have learned something. Anyway I voted him up.

Comment: @45465 Sorry I really didn't mean to offend. I take back what I said, which wasn't nice. Have a good one.